# Jquery ajax response text not complete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, maps

I have a page in which I have to reload latitudes and longitudes to refresh a Google map. I do this using ajax, the JS function is this:

```
function refreshMap(idCamiones)
{

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "refresh.php",
    data: "idCamiones="+idCamiones,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    success : function(text)
        {
             refresh = text;
         }
});

//Borramos todos los marcadores actuales
for (i in markersArray) {markersArray[i].setMap(null);}
markersArray.length=0;

//generamos un array con las latitudes en pares y las longitudes en nones.
posArray=refresh.split(",");
for(i=0;i<=posArray.length;i=i+2)
{
addMarker(2,posArray[i],posArray[i+1]);
}
}
```

`refresh` is a global JS variable which stores the response from the PHP file. If I call the PHP file using the browser the data is complete, I'm supossed to get `(posArrray[0],..,posArray[n])` but if I call the PHP using the JS function the JS variable only saves `(posArray[n-1],posArray[n])` and all the other coordinates are missing just in the JS variable my PHP script works well.

```
<?php
include_once("conexion.php");
$idCamiones=$_GET['idCamiones'];
$reponse='';
$query="SELECT * from datos INNER JOIN dbo.eventos ON eventos.codigo=datos.codigo where id IN (
Select max(id) from datos where camion in (".$idCamiones.") group by serie)  order by serie";
$bD=new COM("ADODB.Recordset");
$bD->Open($query,$conn);
$busData=fetch_assoc($bD);
$bD->close();
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($busData);$i++)
{
$response.=$busData[$i]['latitud'].",".$busData[$i]['longitud'].",";
}
    echo $response;
```

?>

I dont know if I'm returning the $response in the php file incorrectly, I also tried with `refresh=$.ajax({}).responseText;` and I get the same results.

Comment: You said that you are supposed to get a list of latitudes and longitudes, and your `for` loop in the PHP seems to support this. However, [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) only returns an array for the current record, not the entire recordset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your AJAX url+parameters directly in your browser's address bar and see what the response it.

If you have FF and Firebug, you can use the NET -> XHR tab to inspect the request and the response directly.

Comment: calling it directly on the browser gives me all the results , but while using firebug just one parameter is sent within the function not 3 as it should be!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved thanks , the problem was in the parameter sent in the function refreshMap(9,15,17) the PHP script took 9 as the only value so i just added quotes to send the parameter as a string and that did the trick, thank you both i forgot about firebug i was just using chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

If you alert(text) does that give the right info? What about the console in Firebug, when you look at the response there, is it correct, or incorrect?

I have my own map like this, but I haven't had this particular problem. I've never seen an ajax query send less than what I saw in the browser, unless it was a problem with xml breaking.

Why are you using that particular content type? I've only used XML or HTML.

Comment: well using alert(text) the same two last items of the array are shown, but while using firebug i realized that when the function is called there is just one parameter refreshMap(9) when it should be something like refreshMap(9,15,17)  ,but then i checked the function on my html document and it looks like this var intervalo=window.setInterval('refreshMap(9,15,17)',1000);